# Category Hierarchy (in order) using PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, hierarchy

I am trying to **ORDER** my all categories and sub-categories in a hierarchy:

The main point is how to get them from MySQL ORDERLY (using **POSITION** field)

- Cat A    *--> position 10*

  - Sub-Cat 1     *--> position 10*
  - Sub_Sub_Cat 1     *--> position 20*

    - Sub_Sub_Cat 2     *--> position 10*
  - Sub_Cat 2     *--> position 30*
- Cat B    *--> position 20*
- Cat C    *--> position 30*

MySQL code:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
   `category_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `position` smallint(5) unsigned,
   `parent_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to traverse the tree using SQL? That is not possible with the adjacency list model, you have to use the [nested sets model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). Then you can just `ORDER BY left` to get the whole tree in the correct order.

Comment: Wow, that is incredibly cool. I can't believe I never saw this before! This does explain the strange 'lft' and 'rgt' fields in some databases though ;)